# How to get the general solution from its canonical form! pde

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have the pde: 
$u_{xx}-y^2u_{yy}=yu_y$ , y>0.

I want to find the general solution u(x,y), so first I found the canonical form and got: 
$u_{\zeta\eta}$+${u_\zeta}*1/2$+${u_\eta}$*1/2=0 , then I thought about a method from this to find the general solution u(x,y) but did not succeed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a mistake in calculating, the correct canonical form is $u_\zeta\eta=0$ which is solvable..